# Dynamic JSON parsing in. net core

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

We have N number of JSON parameters and class properties as well but
have to remove dynamically the JSON parameters which are not available in class properties while serializing.

If I use `[JsonIgnore]` it is only removing values, not the entire property; we need to remove the entire property.

Example:

JSON request:

```
{
    "Name":"ABC",
    "Age":26,
    "Designation":"Er",
    "Place":"Pune",
    "Gender":"Male"
}
```

Class:

```
[Serializable]
public class SampleProperties
{
    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Designation")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }
}
```

Result Expecting :

```
{
    "Name":"ABC",
    "Age":26,
    "Designation":"Er"
}
```

Comment: Does this question help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595027/net-core-remove-null-fields-from-api-json-response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core: Remove null fields from API JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595027/net-core-remove-null-fields-from-api-json-response)

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this is to create an object with 30 fields and deserialize the json string to this object 
try somthing like this :

```
class MyObject
{
    public string prop1 {get;set; }
    public string prop2 {get;set; }
}
```

then :

```
string json = "your json";
MyObject objectWith30Fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `NullValueHandling` like the code below that you can see on the [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm) of Newtonsoft.Json or in this [link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm) as well, in addition, you can use `ExpandoObject()` as you can see on this [link](http://www.siddharthpandey.net/use-newtonsoft-json-dynamic-expandoobject-objects/)

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Classification { get; set; }
    public string Studio { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public List<string> ReleaseCountries { get; set; }
}

Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.Name = "Bad Boys III";
movie.Description = "It's no Bad Boys";

string included = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { });

// {
//   "Name": "Bad Boys III",
//   "Description": "It's no Bad Boys",
//   "Classification": null,
//   "Studio": null,
//   "ReleaseDate": null,
//   "ReleaseCountries": null
// }

string ignored = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });

// {
//   "Name": "Bad Boys III",
//   "Description": "It's no Bad Boys"
// }
```

More about [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netcore-2.2)