# Remove nulls from IActionResult responses

Tags: c#, azure, json.net, azure-functions

I would like to set a global setting for not returning `null` properties in any response returned from any of my HTTP functions.

Example:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[FunctionName("HttpTriggeredFunction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Id = 1,
        FirstName = "Chris",
        LastName = null
    };

    return new OkObjectResult(user);
}
```

returns:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Chris",
    "lastName": null
}
```

In the above example, I want `lastName` to not be returned in the response.

I'm aware you can do things like:

```cs
[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't want to have to decorate every class.

In Web API, in the `Startup.cs` file, you could do something like this:

```cs
services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(jsonOptions =>
{
    jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET Core: Remove null fields from API JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595027/net-core-remove-null-fields-from-api-json-response)

Comment: @J.Bergmann that looks like what I need but I get this error at runtime `Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcJsonOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it's almost the same settings as it's in web api.

In azure function, you can use `Dependency Injection`, and then register `services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(xxx)`. For DI in azure function, you can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#prerequisites).

First, please make sure you have the following nuget packages installed(I'm using azure function v3 in this test):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.3" />
```

Then in your azure function project, create a class named `Startup.cs`. Here is the code of this class:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//add this line of code here.
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp6.Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp6
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(jsonOptions =>
            {
                jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then run your azure function, the null value will be removed. Here is the screenshot of the test result:

[image]

Comment: I actually found out how to do it in the end and this answer describes it perfectly so will mark as accepted! Thanks Ivan.

Answer (score 1):

Use **JsonIgnore Attribute**,if you can't return LastName Property in response:

```
[JsonIgnore]
 public string LastName { get; set; }
```

if value of that property is null, don't return property in response:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
 public string LastName { get; set; }
```

**global setting way:**
In Startup.cs, you can attach JsonOptions in ConfigureServices method (Asp.net Core 3.+):

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options => {
     options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
});
```

Comment: Sorry but you did not read the question. I want a global way of doing this NOT per property/class.

Comment: @chris please see this link : https://forums.asp.net/t/2067030.aspx?Supress+null+values+in+Web+API+Response