# Azure Functions .NET 6 - remove null fields from response JSON

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0

I'm looking for a way in Azure Functions v4 with .NET 6 to remove null fields from the response JSON. None of the options described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595027/net-core-remove-null-fields-from-api-json-response) worked for me.

I would like these fields be omitted, currently just using `return new OkObjectResult(result);` (result being a list of objects)

[image]

Comment: You can use the `JsonSerializerOptions` to achieve this - try this: `JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions { DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull }`

Comment: where exactly should I use that @marc_s?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result something like this (replacing the current `return` you have):

```
return new JsonResult(myObject, new JsonSerializerOptions() 
                                    { 
                                        DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull
                                    });
```

Comment: thanks! Looks like I need to use Newtonsoft JSON for this, right? Or is there a way to do this using System.Text.Json?

Comment: `JsonSerializerOptions` **is** from `System.Text.Json` .....

Comment: strange, according to the docs it should work, but I'm getting `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'`