# IActionResult without null values object

Tags: c#, .net-core

Im using  this code(C#NETCORE5.0) to return a model:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
        public IActionResult GetTablero(GenericStringModel item){
            TableroVentasManager mng = new TableroVentasManager();
            TablaGeneralVentasModel response = mng.getTotalTable(item.zona);         
            return response != null ? Ok(response) : BadRequest();
        }
```

I want to reduce the size of the response (16.6mb actual) I have use

```
string ignored = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

but  the size increase to 24mb

But if I only return the model, the size is 16.6MB   theres a way to ignore null values to reduce the size?

Actual:

```
{
            "zona": "Z305",
            "companyId": "C018763",
            "formaEnvio": "CCI FORANEO",
            "mov": "salesorder",
            "tranId": 1193156,
            "subTotal": 164.8800,
            "consolidado": null,
            "nombre": "Ingresado",
            "fechaIngreso": "2022-12-02T10:39:56",
            "fechaLiberado": null,
            "fechaProceso": null,
            "fechaCancelado": null,
            "consolidado2": 0.0,
            "empacado": 0
        }
```

Desired:

```
 {
            "zona": "Z305",
            "companyId": "C018763",
            "formaEnvio": "CCI FORANEO",
            "mov": "salesorder",
            "tranId": 1193156,
            "subTotal": 164.8800,            
            "nombre": "Ingresado",
            "fechaIngreso": "2022-12-02T10:39:56",          
            "consolidado2": 0.0,
            "empacado": 0
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507889/how-to-ignore-a-property-in-class-if-null-using-json-net

Comment: You can configure serialization options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595027/net-core-remove-null-fields-from-api-json-response

Comment: @AndroFont Thats do the job,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `response` is a List, can you perhaps use Linq to filter out null values:

`response.RemoveAll(x => x == null)`

Then return your `Ok(response)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a compression mechanism something like `GZIP`. [Readmore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ;

1. Install the package:

   `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server`
2. Browse your solution to the `App_Start` folder then open the `WebApiConfig.cs` file, we will import two libs from the package we installed.

   `using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression.Server;`

   `using System.Net.Http.Extensions.Compression.Core.Compressors;`
3. Finally at the end of the Register method the following line

   `config.MessageHandlers.Insert(0, new ServerCompressionHandler(new GZipCompressor(), new DeflateCompressor()));`

Before gzip application:

[image]

After gzip application:

[image]