# Dynamic Response doesn't return the property tag which is assigned null. I need the element in the response atleast

Tags: c#, api, null, response, return-value-optimization

I have a post API with a return type as Dynamic.
I return a class object after processing my logic.

There are cases when I need to assign null to certain properties in the class object. When this is returned, the received response does not have those elements which are assigned with null.
Example sited below:
Class object:

```
     public class ModDetailResponse
    {
            public int element1{ get; set; }
            public int element2{ get; set; }
}
```

After some logic, I assign values to it:

```
  ModDetailResponse modDetail = new ModDetailResponse();
 modDetail.element1= 123;
 modDetail.element2= null;
```

Now the API returns only one value:

```
{element1:123}
```

That's it.

If element 2 has some value, it returns it. I need the null value as well.

Can someone help?

Comment: Possibly covered by this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418549/custom-json-serializer-for-optional-property-with-system-text-json

Answer (score 0):

This is due to json serializer settings on your .Net application. Different .Net versions have different ways of dealing with this and different default behavior.

Please see stackoverflow question [.NET Core: Remove null fields from API JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595027/net-core-remove-null-fields-from-api-json-response) it contains many examples for different .Net versions on how to configure enabling or disabling this behavior.